# The operator '*' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '*' error

Tags: android, flutter, dart, object

```
        body:Center(
          child: TweenAnimationBuilder(
            tween: Tween(begin: 0.0,end: 1.0),
            duration: Duration(seconds: 4),
            builder: (context,value,child){
              int percentage = (value! * 100).ceil();
              return Container(
                width: size,
                height: size,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    ShaderMask(
                      shaderCallback: (rect){
                        return SweepGradient(
                            startAngle: 0.0,
                            endAngle: TWO_PI,
                            stops: const [0.0,0.5],
                            // 0.0 , 0.5 , 0.5 , 1.0
                            center: Alignment.center,
                            colors: [Colors.blue,Colors.grey.withAlpha(55)]
                        ).createShader(rect);
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        width: size,
                        height: size,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            image: DecorationImage(image: Image.asset("assets/images/radial_scale.png").image)
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

int percentage = (value! * 100).ceil(); I can't do multiplication in line of code.
**The operator '*' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '*'.** I get this error.

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell the builder what kind of value you are animating, in this case a `double`, like this:

```
TweenAnimationBuilder<double>(
```

Comment: Got it, thank you, my problem is solved.